# How big website like facebook and google push the code changes without affecting website

Tags: web-deployment

I am very curious to know about the website like facebook and google, how they manage its website, if we talk about our own website, when there new changes come, and it we push that changes on our live server, it will stop our website untill the full code push to live server, but as far as facebook,google websites are concern, i never seen their website down and how they push the code without affecting its own site ? How they manage their website ?

Comment: @simon Thanks for help